# how to manage cache tornado login

Tags: caching, webserver, tornado

I have a tornado webserver with login page:

If the client try to access any endpoint it checks if the user is logged in and if he isn't then is redirected to login endpoint for the user log in.

The problem is that if i allow cache in the browser then when i access to any endpoint i have been before, the browser try to be clever and begin to requests all css and static files inside that endpoint despite that all of the requests are being redirected to login page provoking strange behaviors.

I could add in all my responses no-cache headers but i wanted to know if this is a good approach or is there a better management of this case.

Comment: I don't think the browser will request all static files by itself (it will only request those that are referenced in your page).

Comment: The default static file handler for Tornado does not use authentication (which should work OK for you). Can you post your static handler definition?

Comment: Im using secure_cookie as authentication and, the cookie, is generated by a third party api. Im using the default static file handler. And the problem with static files is, that ones i enter one time in the page (after authentication) the browser store all files in cache making that the next times i access to that endpoint automatically request all files even if i didnt auth